# How to set visibility of a radio button field in Orbeon form based on two other fields

Tags: if-statement, nested, conditional-statements, logical-operators, orbeon

I am creating an Orbeon form in which I have two yes/no fields and third one is radio button.

- If `field 1` is set to `Yes`. `Field 2` and `field 3` are visible.
- If `Field 1` is set to `Yes` and `field 2` is set `No` then `field 3` should be hidden.

I am not able to set the visibility in it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fields have the names `field1`, `field2`, and `field3`, then you should set the visibility of:

- `field2` to `$field1/string() = 'true'`
- `field3` to `$field1/string() = 'true' and $field2/string() = 'false'`

For more on this, see [Testing on a Yes/No Answer field](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas-examples.html#testing-on-a-yes-no-answer-field).

Comment: All the three fields are radio button.
field1 is radio button with two values in it as 'yes'/'no'
field2 is another radio button with two values in it as 'yes'/'no'
field3 is another radio button with three values in it '3','4','5'

The function you provided does not support in this case.

Comment: @AmanShah You only need to use the method described in my answer, i.e. `$yesno-name/string() = 'true'`, for Yes/No fields. For radio buttons, you can just use `$radio-name = 'value'`, where `value` is the value you provided in the "Edit Choices" dialog. You'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped!!